# Outlook 2003 Not Sending eMail

Tags: outlook

I have a client who has recently developed a problem with Outlook.

When attempting to send an email by clicking the send button, nothing happens. After a while, the email is saved to the Drafts folder, but nothing else, the email is not placed in the Outbox.

Clicking send and receive, gets any email from the server that is on there. There are no error messages.

The primary mail server is an Exchange Server, but there is also an ISP account. I cannot send email using either of these. The Exchange Server does not have a method to test the account setting, but the ISP does. When I test this, it sends and receives without any errors.

It looks to me like the Outlook send button is broken. Does this seem probable?

Prior to this happening, the multiple .Net frameworks on the machine needed to be deleted and reinstalled. I was wondering if this could be the problem, but I didn't think that Outlook 2003 used the .Net Frameworks at all.

Comment: Does the server require outgoing authentication? I've found, on occasion, that check box (in the account settings) becomes unchecked and I need to re-enter the log in credentials again.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Brad. I did look at that, and it is set up to authenticate. However, as I mentioned above, running the test still sends the test message, would that happen if the account itself wasn't set up properly?

The other clue is that when clicking send, the message is not placed in the outbox. Nothing happens at all, until the message is saved as a draft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable all third party add-ins.

I have seen corrupt installations of Adobe Acrobat cause this issue in the past. If any add-ins required a .net framework that is still corrupt it could be causing the failure.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this problem now. I solved it in another computer a long time ago by disabling Adobe Creative Cloud, then uninstalling and reinstalling Office 2003. It worked then!